# Newbie and data SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

Hey I am newbie and I have a little problem with one of my classes. Because last row gives me like 5 different errors and i really dont know what to do about it.
Thanks for help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace INformační_Systém
{
    class DataAcess
    {
       public void WriteName(string databaseName, string where_content, string what_content)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string insrt;
            string connectionstring = Helper.GetInfo(databaseName);
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            cnn.Open();
            insrt = "insert into " databaseName; " ("; + where_content; ") values(" + what_content ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: Can you provide the errors you are getting?

Comment: You _connect_ to _database_, and you _insert_ data into a _table_. (And a database typically consists of many tables.)

Comment: I edited post and if you click on errors you can see them, afterall I guess its more like syntax errors not errors with sql connection. But idk

Comment: Start fixing your bugs? Most are trivial syntax bugs - like ending writing a variable name into a list of strings without "+" in betweren and - ah - terminating the line in a variable name and then going on

Comment: And generally you only care about the FIRST bug. And no, copy/paste random code will not work.

Comment: Always use SQL Server Management Studio to test your queries before trying them in c#.  The error messages are much better in SSMS than in c#.

Comment: Thats my code and there's the problem, I dont know how to fix them (syntax error) I was like half an hour and trying to fix syntax but I really dont know. I have a little of programming experience. I was doing in python from 17.12.2019 to 27.1.2020 and i am doing in c# like 5 days.

Comment: On the Web page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it is written that you should research your question before posting it. Did you look for example code in C# that performs an insert into a database table?

Comment: @Brog the best place to start is *the documentation*. [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) is extensively covered in Microsoft's docs and courses. There are a ton of tutorials, how tos, books, and articles. Check the [ADO.NET Code Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples) from the docs

Comment: But this is not an ADO.NET issue - this is pur and simply C# syntax when doing string manipulation. Not having "+" between string segments and adding ";" within a line of code is not proper C# - that you later send this string to the database does not come into these bugs at all, they are way more basic than this. He is not even sending bad SQL - he is failing in basic C# syntax for string manipulation with compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

All your errors are on the same line and they are typical syntax errors that a beginner who never learned the language properly, like with a book, makes.

> insrt = "insert into " databaseName; " ("; + where_content; ") v

Let's see

- insrt

Spelling mistake. Seriously. It is "insert". (You are missing the letter *e*.)

- "insert into " databaseName;

You cannot add names into strings by just appending the name. Do you want to make one string? That would be "insert into" + databaseName - note the "+". You THEN end the line with ";" and THEN go in on with another string - that is rubbish. The line does not end there, so no ";" but another "+"

And this error repeats. You are in love with randomly adding ";" and then wondering about the compile errors.

And note that this is the worst code for years. Look up SQL Injection attack to start with - parameters, and if you need dynamic SQL look at something like EF to construct type safe SQL statements. Unless you have super good code on the UI side OR use something like static strings you basically invite people to abuse your database.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I now have my code working :). I will take a look at some of referenced you mentioned. This is woking code: insrt = "insert into" + databaseName + " ( " + where_content + ") values(" + what_content + ")";              Again thanks now I see how dumb it was :)

Answer (score -1):

```
insrt = "insert into "+ databaseName+" (" + where_content +") values(" + what_content ")";
```

Comment: Hi,
This is actually a really dangerous piece of code because it is vulnerable to Sql Injection - it's allow an attacker to do lots of nasty things to your db, and possibly your entire server
https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection